# Decrypting AES in C# encrypted in SQL Anywhere 12.0 or earlier

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, sqlanywhere

There is a [similar discussion about encrypting and decrypting in SA16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530926/decrypting-aes-in-sql-anywhere-16-encrypted-in-c-sharp-and-vise-versa) where it works with minor issues, but there I have a more specific and problematic question: I do understant why SA12 can not decrypt stuff encrypted in other systems, because it does not has the capability of setting up specific parameters, but what about the other way around, decrypting stuff in C# encrypted in SA12 or earlier? All I know from [SA12 documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1200/en/dbreference/encrypt-function.html) is that it uses Rijndael algorithm and has a random IV and the size 128 or 256 can be specified, but I do not know the padding, the cipher mode and am not sure about the data rawness format.

So long story short: Is it possible to decrypt data encrypted in SA12 outside of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in v12. The algorithm itself is AES, but the way we break the data up into blocks for encryption, the IV we use, and the way we store the encrypted data are all proprietary and unpublished.

*Full disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*